# Multiply items from one list with items from another list

Tags: r

I am attempting to apply a calculation to a list of 64 items. I have two lists. The first list is called CJAN, which is a list of 64 linear models containing two numbers - an integer and slope coefficient as shown below. The second list is called JAN.FUT, which is a list of 64 files containing 251 numbers as also shown below.

```
CJAN    List of 64
file1: Named num[1:2] -92.37 1.02
..-attr(*, "names")= chr [1:2] "(Intercept)" "x$x"
-----------------------------------
file64 Named num[1:2] -45.42 0.98
..-attr(*, "names")= chr [1:2] "(Intercept)" "x$x"


JAN.FUT    List of 64
file1: num[1:251] 126 164...
-----------------------------------
file64: num[1:251] 150 126...
```

I want to multiply all the items in the JAN.FUT list with the intercept values from the CJAN list and then add the slope coefficient (x$x) to the resulting calculation. This is my way to get round the difficulty of using the predict function with lists. I have attempted:

```
PRED=lapply(JAN.FUT, function(x) (x*CJAN["x$x"])+CJAN["(Intercept)"])
```

but I get the error message:

```
Error in x * CJAN["x$x"] : non-numeric argument to binary operator
```

Anyone know how to get around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Map`

```
Map(function(x,y){
  x["x$x"] * y + x["(Intercept)"]
}, CJAN, JAN.FUT)
```

Which results in a list of vectors with element-wise `length==length(JAN.FUT)`

```
[[1]]
[1]  3.7419169 -0.1293963  1.7262568  2.2657252  1.8085366

[[2]]
[1]  2.575502  9.046088  2.621364 11.073695  2.749144
```

**Data:**

```
set.seed(42)

CJAN <- list(c("(Intercept)" = 1, "x$x" = 2), c("(Intercept)" = 3, "x$x" = 4))
JAN.FUT <- list(rnorm(5), rnorm(5))
```